# A Question About Linear Interpolation

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, coordinate-systems, interpolation

So lets say I have two points $A=(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ and $B=(x_2, y_2, z_2)$. $A$ and $B$ are each associated with some scalar value $K_1$ and $K_2$. $K_1$ is negative and $K_2$ is positive and all the $K$ values of the points along the line $AB$ linearly go from $K_1$ to $K_2$. How would I linearly interpolate between $A$ and $B$ to find the point $C$ between them whose $K$ value is $0$? Is there an easy way to code this assuming I have a point class?

Comment: From your description, the function $P\in (A,B)\longmapsto K$ could be anything. In particular, it could never reach $0$. So I suspect your assumption is that this function is affine. Right?

Comment: Why would it never reach 0? K1 is negative and K2 is positive. Therefore it has to cross 0 at some point.

Comment: If it is continuous, yes. If it is not continuous, there is no reason. Define $K=32$ for all points but $A$ and $B$, for instance. You need to say more about your function. Apparently, implicitly, you meant $K(tA_1+(1-t)A_2=tK_1+(1-t)K_2$. That is an affine function. Not every function is affine...

Comment: I assumed this was (more or less) taken care of when he stated "all the K values of the points along the line AB linearly go from K1 to K2."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The line connecting A and B can be parameterized $(1-t)A + tB$, and there is some linear function $f(t) = k_1 + k_2 t$ such that $f(0) = K_1, f(1) = K_2$.

> So then, $K_1 = f(0) = k_1$ and $K_2 = f(1) = K_1 + k_2$ so $k_2 = K_2 - K_1$.
>
>  Set $f(t) = K_1 + (K_2 - K_1)t = 0$, and solve for $t = K_1/(K_1 - K_2)$.
>
>  Thus, the point you're looking for is $(1 - K_1/(K_1 - K_2))A + K_1/(K_1 - K_2)B = (1/(K_1 - K_2))(-K_2 A + K_1 B)$

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thank you!

Comment: Looks a little prettier as $(k_2A-k_1B)/(k_2-k_1)$.